# System Restore with a Dual Boot with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot, system-restore

I am dual booting W7 and W8.  When I boot into W7 my restore points are deleted in W8.  When W7 came out there was a registry hack for XP to preserve W7 restore points.  Does something like that exist now for W8?  Here is the link I used to accomplish this:

http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/127417-system-restore-points-stop-xp-dual-boot-delete.html

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried the same process for your Windows 8 partition on Windows 7?